# xpath not getting perfect output from the xml file

Tags: xml, arrays, xpath

this is my xml file:-

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
    <dist_activity value="10068"/>
    <dist_activity value="10070"/>
    <individual_strdt value="2013-01-14 20:35:00"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
    <dist_activity value="10069"/>
    <dist_activity value="10070"/>
    <individual_strdt value="2013-02-14 20:39:00"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

this is my code:-

```
<?php
$abc="10068 in 2013-02-14 20:39:00";
list($one,$two)=explode(' in ',$abc);
$text1[]=$one;
$text2[]=$two;

foreach($text1 as $activity)
{
$actvitiy;
}
foreach($text2 as $date)
{
$date;
}


$p = file_get_contents('product.xml');

$product = simplexml_load_string($p);

list($activity_id) = $product->xpath("//dist_activity['$actvitiy'] | //individual_strdt['$date']/ancestor::product_id/@value");
$activity_id = (string) $activity_id;
?>
<script language="javascript">
alert('<?= $activity_id ?>')
</script>
<?php
if (strlen(trim($activity_id))==0)
{
echo $activity.'&'.$date.' Region Not Match';
exit;
} //check the $entity in product.xml
echo "id:- $activity_id";
?>
```

here i have one string in `$abc` 
i am try to explode them with `in`
and store in to two diff `var`
is return something like this: 
`$one = 10068`
 `$two = 2013-02-14 20:39:00`
try to check in `product.xml` file
$one value with `<dist_activity>`
$two value with `<individual_strdt>`
both are match then return there parent element attribute value like `<product_id>` value `1`(one is output)
**query:-**
now problem is in $abc string both value are diff. element child value`10068` is the `<product_id>` `1` child element and `2013-02-14 20:39:00` is `<product_id>` `2` child element.
now in this case message soud be printed both value are not match 
but its not work its display product_id value `1`

Answer (score 0):

May be you need:

```
list($activity_id) = $product->xpath("//dist_activity[@value = '$actvitiy' ] | //individual_strdt[ @value = '$date']/ancestor::product_id/@value");
```